# Can't Resolve this Issue while uninstalling Kubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kubuntu

**This error is coming**
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:

```
**The following packages have unmet dependencies:**
gir1.2-caribou-1.0 : Depends: libcaribou0 (= 0.4.20-1) but 0.4.13-0ubuntu1 is to be installed 
nmap : Depends: liblinear3 (>= 2.01+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed

Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3 is to be installed
Depends: lua-lpeg but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: ndiff

E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Have you actually tried running `apt-get -f install`?  And what is the output?

Comment: edited the question now u can see

Comment: It looks like you're trying to install packages newer than what's available in your software repositories. Make sure that the packages you are trying to install are compatible with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: i was to install katoolin to install kali tool but and it worked fine since added the linux ppa but now it not working

Comment: [Katoolin](https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin/blob/633150f8217b277ed4ef1808a6cb30edf41b0fa8/katoolin.py#L48) is not compatible with Ubuntu 14.04 because it adds a Kali Linux "bleeding edge" repo, which have different packages from the Ubuntu 14.04 repos.  There are [removal instructions on Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/a/708848/18979).

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to install packages through [Katoolin](https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin), but [Katoolin adds a repository for Kali Linux's "bleeding edge"](https://github.com/LionSec/katoolin/blob/633150f8217b277ed4ef1808a6cb30edf41b0fa8/katoolin.py#L48), not for Ubuntu 14.04, which is your operating system.

As a result, the package versions conflict with each other, and your dependencies cannot be resolved.

You should remove Katoolin using the [instructions on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/708848/18979).

To resolve your dependencies, remove the conflicting software:

```
sudo apt-get remove gir1.2-caribou-1.0 nmap
```

If you want to use Kali Linux packages, you should run Kali Linux.  [Their official documentation](http://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux) says that their software set is designed specifically for Kali Linux:

> While Kali Linux is architected to be [highly customizable](http://docs.kali.org/development/live-build-a-custom-kali-iso), don’t expect to be able to add random unrelated packages and repositories that are “out of band” of the regular Kali software sources and have it Just Work. In particular, there is absolutely no support whatsoever for the apt-add-repository command, LaunchPad, or PPAs. Trying to install ***Steam*** on your Kali Linux desktop is an experiment that will not end well. Even getting a package as mainstream as NodeJS onto a Kali Linux installation can take [a little extra effort and tinkering](http://www.acme-dot.com/stupid-problems-deserve-stupid-solutions/).